# Where is MySQL template directory for pristine Data?

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm using MySQL 8.0 in Windows.

I'm trying to set up multiple servers.  And I need to copy the Data directory for it. [The MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-data-directories.html) says

> Windows MSI package installers create and set up the data directory
> that the installed server will use, but also create a pristine
> “template” data directory named data under the installation directory.
> After an installation has been performed using an MSI package, the
> template data directory can be copied to set up additional MySQL
> instances.

It says there is a pristine data directory that is not touched. But my Data directories are already modified because I used it quite a long time. I need to copy the Data directory to make new server.
Where do I find the pristine Data directory?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone met the same problem as me, I couldn't find the pristine Data directory. I looked everywhere but I couldn't. So I reinstalled the new copy on my second computer. And copy the Data folder from it. Now, my multiple servers work without any problem in one machine.